# How can such a nested generic method be resolved?

Tags: c#, generics

#### Description

I would like to create a generic method with a single generic type input that has the return type of the generic parameter of the supplied type input.

*In the context of this problem, having an instance parameter is not an option as instances would not exist in the callers context.*

#### Example

Given the following interface:

```
interface IFoo<T> { }
```

What I am trying to achieve is something along the lines of the following *improper* method declarations.

```
TInner GetFoo<T>() where T : IFoo<TInner>;
```

```
T GetFoo<IFoo<T>>();
```

Which would be used like so:

```
class FooA : IFoo<int> { }

int foo = GetFoo<FooA>();
```

#### Question

How would such a method be declared properly (if it is even possible)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `TInner GetFoo<T>() where T : IFoo<TInner>` signature does not even make use the IFoo<T> type as argument. Why **precisely** do you need an IFoo<T> there in the method declaration? Why not just declare the method like `TInner GetFoo<TInner>()` ?

Comment: @itsme86 As described in the usage example, an `IFoo<T>` type is considered to be an input to this theoretical method, where I would like to extract `IFoo<T>`'s `T` generic as the output of the method. The examples above only shows the signature I am going for, the actual method body would do other operations based on that type.

Comment: Well, if you want to do that, you have to swallow the pill of using a signature like: `TInner GetFoo<T, TInner>() where T : IFoo<TInner>`, which would be really akward to use. Depending on what your GetFoo method actually does, there might perhaps be different ways out of this conundrum, but it is impossible to say without knowing precisely what the implementation of GetFoo is supposed to be...

Comment: @elgonzo I see. The actual behaviour of `IFoo<T>` and `GetFoo` is fairly involved, but I do believe there is another way to restructure my problem which would not involve the syntax you mentioned (and I feared as well).
Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comment by elgonzo, the most natural solution to your problem is a declaration of the form

```
TInner GetFoo<T, TInner>() where T : IFoo<TInner>
```

Although your idea of declaring it as `TInner GetFoo<T>() where T : IFoo<TInner>` is *sensible*, this is currently unsupported. It is akin to *higher kinded parametric polymorphism* a feature dearly awaited by functional programming enthusiasts.